# Can we do CRUD Operation in hibernate without hbm2ddl.auto property?

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, orm

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update/validate</prop>
```

without above property in configuration file, Can we do all the CRUD operation in hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Yes. `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property only runs DDL statements and is not used to fetch data from table.

update

The above statement means that it will update the table if hbm is updated.

Comment: so to get data from table, do we need this property in cfg file?

Comment: No, this property is not used to fetch data from table.

Comment: so without using this property in cfg file, can we do CRUD operation ?

Comment: for crud follow this link http://websystique.com/spring/spring4-hibernate4-mysql-maven-integration-example-using-annotations/

Comment: In given link, he didn't used hbm2ddl.auto property anywhere in his code, so i confirm that we don't need to use that property to do CRUD.

Comment: Yes bro, hbm2ddl.auto has nothing to do with CRUD. hbm2ddl.auto is configuration and CRUD is implementation.